# Do Americans say "don't" as often as the British?

Tags: word-usage, american-english, contractions, contemporary-english

This is really a question for Americans.

When watching US TV or films, it's often my impression that—while using all the other contractions—Americans don't seem so keen on 'don't' and use 'do not' rather more often than we Brits. I also don't think this difference only occurs when it is stressed.

Any comments?

Comment: I think perhaps you will find comparatively more "do not"s in series or films because they are based on written scripts. Even so, you may be right – I have no idea.

Comment: Can you give some examples of this?

Comment: @Cerberus - No, I don't think it's that. As I said 'while using all the other contractions'.@Everyone else - And no sorry, I don't have any evidence. As I said, it's only an impression. But thanks guys for trying. I'm very new here, but I'm beginning to recognise the monikers of the 'usual suspects'.

Comment: @RandomIdeaEnglish: You're right, I should have reread.

Comment: OK, it took about ten seconds on YouTube - first Friends I found, - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZedZ2Vw7Fqk - about twenty seconds in - 'I do not love getting divorced' - maybe I have a possible answer - I accept that there could be a bit of emphasis here, but as far as I can tell, David Schwimmer stresses the two words 'do not' equally, whereas in BrE we would come down much more heavily on the 'not'. So perhaps I'm hearing stressed, but thinking it's not stressed. What do you think?

Comment: Hmm I am not sure. While neither the volume nor the length of "not" were increased, I did seem to hear a higher pitch. I think I'd still count it as stressed, though I am no expert.

Comment: I believe there was a while in the US where contractions were thought of as "stupid" or "lazy."  I blame the 90s.

Comment: I remember this anecdote about a student during a lecture about linguistics standing up and saying: I don't say "don't!"

Comment: In the friends episode he was definitely using an emphatic "not", but in the flow of natural conversation it isn't highly exaggerated. He's not just saying "I don't know" or "I don't think so" or something like that, he saying (emphatically) "I do *not* enjoy getting divorced!'

Comment: Maybe Random has been watching too much Star Trek.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I did some searches in the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=8201178) and compared the results to similar searches in the [British National corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/?c=bnc&q=8201183).

What I found was that overall, in American English there was a 7.9-to-1 ratio of *don’t* to *do not*. With breakdowns by type:

| Section | Frequency |
| --- | --- |
| SPOKEN | 19.6 |
| FICTION | 17.9 |
| MAGAZINE | 7.5 |
| NEWSPAPER | 7.7 |
| ACADEMIC | 0.5 |
| TOTAL | 7.9 |

In British English overall, the ratio was 4.4-to-1 in favor of *don’t*, with breakdowns by type:

| Section | Frequency |
| --- | --- |
| SPOKEN | 56.9 |
| FICTION | 16.8 |
| MAGAZINE | 4.1 |
| NEWSPAPER | 3.4 |
| NON-ACAD | 0.9 |
| ACADEMIC | 0.2 |
| MISC | 0.9 |

So, if it is reasonable to conclude anything from this data, it is that Americans overall use *don’t* about twice as frequently as the British, but the British use *don’t* in speech about 2.9 times more frequently than Americans. In any case, these are not big enough ratios to be noticeable by anyone not counting every incidence.

Comment: Brilliant, backing up your answer with statistics. +1

Comment: It's also possible that the higher incidence in BrE comes about from popular localized constructions that often use the word "don't".

Comment: @nohat brilliant answer, +1. @treeface out of curiousity, can you make an example of such a localized construction?

Comment: Thanks for all your work, Nohat, my question was exclusively about spoken English, as I said, on TV and in films. In which case, if I'm reading your figures correctly, Americans don't seem to use 'don't' nearly as much as us when speaking, but use it rather more than us in print. I know that some people in the UK (but not me) consider contractions inappropriate for the printed word. So I think one way or another you've answered my question. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I'd just like to add something. I've just done a check on Google Ngram Viewer, which seems to back up your findings. In American English, and this is from books of course, 'don't' has streaked ahead since about 1980. But in British English, 'do not' is still ahead by quite a margin. Fascinating how we've gone for 'don't' big time when it comes to speaking, but are reluctant to use it in print, whereas Americans seem to have gone the other way.

Comment: Well, it's hard to draw too many conclusions from this data because the British National Corpus contains data up to 1992, whereas COCA has data to 2010. Also, the spoken corpora probably weren't made from the same kinds of utterances. I think COCA's spoken corpus is mainly TV transcripts, whereas BNC's is mainly meeting minutes and lectures.

Comment: Some British dialects tend not to use "don't": many Scottish and north of English dialects use "dinnae" or "dinna" or similar, while Scots also has other, related negative constructions (often from early modern English/Scots) such as putting "not"/"no" after the verb where southern English would use "n't" forms. "gonnae no dae that", "Ah'm no happy", etc.

Answer (score 4):

I think we use "don't" and "can't" almost exclusively in normal conversation here in the U.S. "Do not" and "cannot" are reserved for making special emphasis or dramatic effect. But we have a long history of using the word "don't" — particularly in admonishing our former colonial masters. Have a look at this colonial American flag (Gadsden Flag, source: Wikipedia).

[image: yellow "don't tread on me" flag with snake]

And its naval equivalent:

[image: red and white striped "don't tread on me" flag with red and yellow snake]

Comment: These flags were created during the Revolutionary War, weren't they?  This was when British and Americans likely had very little difference in their manner of speaking.  In any case, I don't really think the observation was that we *never* use "don't".

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Actually the flags were created c. 1754, during the time of the French and Indian War. They were employed early on in the revolution, eventually being superseded by the "Old Glory" we're all familiar with now. (Interesting side note: cf. the flag of the British East India Company — http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_East_India_Company — which predates the American flag.) In any case, I stated my belief about usage in the first sentence of my answer. I only included the flags for a little bit of humor at the end.

Comment: These flags are important evidence and deserve an upvote.

Comment: @Cerberus: How are the flags important evidence?  These are examples of English over 250 years ago, when we were still British Colonies.  And it only shows that the word "don't" was ever used at least once, not that it is used as much as the British do.  Even Robusto says the flags were added for humor.

Comment: @Cerberus, @Kosomonaut: As I said, I included the flags (and my closing remarks) as a humorous (I hoped) parting shot at our British friends, not as evidence of anything. If anything, they constitute a lagniappe. Also, they add a little color to the page.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: Hey, are you using devious counter irony on me, or did I disguise the irony in my comment too well? The real reason for my upvote was what he wrote above the flags, though I did like the flags.

Comment: @Robusto: I know. I can only say it is a pity that the Dutch didn't keep New Amsterdam – we'd have dealt with you guys differently!

Comment: @Cerberus, @Robusto: Without citing any specific threads, if I assumed every response that sounded absurd was dry wit, I'd probably end up insulting people left and right :) As for this thread, no need to be so stingy with the emoticons... help a guy out here!

Comment: @Kosmonaut: I appreciate your trying to take everyone seriously, that is polite. I happen to have this problem in bars: when a stranger approaches me with some chat-up line, I will often respond in a serious manner and think "why do people ask such bad questions?". Then I come off as impolite. // I'm afraid I can't do emoticons (mostly out of ignorance and self-prescriptivism).

Comment: @Rhodri: That would have been a worthy cause!Then again, repressing silly revolutions can be fun as well... and profitable.

Comment: @Cerberus: In online discussion boards, IMs, and other chat-like discussions, I prescribe that one must always use the smiley `:)`, winky-smiley `;)`, or sarcasm tag `/s` whenever one writes a non-obvious sarcastic comment.  To do anything else is completely wrong and has no place in the English language. I write papers on English sometimes, so I am an authority figure on the topic. Did that help? :)

Comment: @Cerberus, @Rhodri: Actually, I kind of hate having to use apostrophes. If the trend in languages is toward simplification, surely this would be a worth target for the blue pencil. Faulkner eschewed the apostrophe in his contractions, and I think he was on to something. Too bad it never caught on.

Comment: @Kosmonaut: I am having doubts. While on the one hand communist space-farers have something going for them, I am afraid your reference to a potentially scientific perspective ("papers") disqualifies you as a prescriptionist. Science equals doubt equals weakness. It also implies that you didn't stick to the trusty knowledge you possessed after elementary school. Oh, but I do appreciate that you added a smiley after your last comment, or I'd have taken it seriously.

Comment: @Cerberus: Frowny face :(

Answer (score 3):

I'm new to the site. I stumbled across this forum question, because as a British ESOL Tutor, living in the USA for the past 25 years, my lesson for my students tonight is about "contractions"! I, from my own personal experience have observed and noted, that the spoken contraction (don't) is definitely 'spoken' less frequently, by all and sundry, around Palm Beach County where I reside. In fact, as a Brit, I treasure be a proud and frequent speaker of contractions, especially (don't!) but my oldest teenage son and his teenage buddies rarely speak this contraction. They, in fact, to my observant ear, only say "do not"! I'm constantly admonishing my son for not saying "don't!", instead choosing his wording in a similar vein to his fellow teens. I will, however, bring to your attention, that my son likes to text IDK, in place of "I don't know". Which then makes me in turn chuckle, because of his infrequent use of the contraction "don't". I need to draw to his attention his acronym doesn't make sense unless he actually uses the contraction "don't" in his conversation, because his acronym should instead read IDNK (I do not know)!

Comment: Hello HLM, and welcome to the site. It's great to hear from someone who has many years experience with both dialects, somewhat a rarity around these parts, which is why I upvoted your unsupported but useful answer nevertheless.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response.Yes, I can say, I know both sides of the story as far both the American and UK version of English, after having resided here for 25 years. Sometimes, I find myself in doubt over traditional English words that I haven't heard spoken here in the States.I always find watching a dose of good British drama on PBS on a Sunday reminds me of my British English roots. As for supporting evidence, the only way to corroborate would be to capture my son's text messages,which frequently make me wince with grammatical errors and a deficit of genuine contractions! Oh well ;)

Comment: Hello again! Maybe, when you have the time, you could post an answer to this question: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/282673/quite-in-ame-vs-bre (a warning: you need 50 rep points before you are given the "privilege" of posting a comment on users' posts, you can post comments if you are the author of a question or an answer) I'm finding it hard to believe that the phrase "there were quite fifty people in the house." is grammatical, let alone BrEng.

Comment: I have used the expression "there were not quite as many as myself" many times over. But not the exact expression that you wrote above. It does, however, sound correct to my British ear, especially when I mull it over a couple of times!

Answer (score 2):

I don't doubt that we say "don't" in the US as much as our cousins across the pond.

That is, I expect usage is similar in the US and UK.

Comment: I think you're right, but do you have any actually evidence?

Comment: @JSBangs: Does RandomIdeaEnglish have any?  It sounds like a very difficult thing to prove.  If there is no difference in the usage of "don't", then nobody is going to investigate it or write a paper on it.  So one of us would have to do it ourselves.  But you couldn't go and compare a British corpus to an American corpus... you would need something else.

Comment: @JSBangs - No, I don't :-) Seriously, I don't know how one would go about obtaining evidence.

Answer (score 2):

I've voted for nohat's answer, because of the evidence, but I offer my observations anyway:

I find that Americans generally use accepted contractions, including *don't*.  I rarely hear *do not* except for emphasis.  Another data point:  In *Star Trek: The Next Generation*, Worf and Data are conspicuous for their contraction-free speech, again including *don't* (Worf is formal by choice; Data has some kind of weird programming deficiency).  This is actually played up in the show from time to time.  Everyone else uses *don't* freely.

Answer (score 0):

When I was young I was taught not to use contractions in my written works.  I wonder if the same English style conventions were taught in the UK, and if that has any effect on American and UK script writers or not.

I believe children are now being taught to write more conversationally, and contractions are not frowned on in written language as much as they used to be.

Answer (score 0):

As the saying goes, “there are three kinds of lies: lies, damned lies, and statistics.” Well, statistics be damned! As an American who has lived and traveled from east to west, and as someone who has spent my career in broadcasting, I assure you that we don’t use “don’t” in everyday speech any less than our British cousins, and possibly more so. I hope that don’t confuse you...

Comment: Please don't miss the [tour] and the [FAQ] on how to answer.