# "Quite" American vs British English

Tags: word-usage, idioms, american-english, british-english, transatlantic-differences

In looking at the answers for this question, [Using "quite" with a noun](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/282614/129806), it occurred to me that "quite," although having a dictionary definition, might be used differently by AmE and BrE speakers such that it is not correct to speak about "the correct" use of "quite."

Case in point, WS2's example sentence:

> There were quite a few hundred at the gathering

to my ear (AmE) sounds "wrong," but in the UK this might be everyday usage.

Also the following:

> There were quite 50 people at the house

is something I would express using *about* / *actually* / *around* instead of *quite*.

- Is there a significant usage difference between BrE and AmE usage of "quite?"

This could be viewed as "opinion based" but perhaps there is an objective answer.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: I am sure there are differences between the U.S. and the U.K. in the usage of *quite*, but *were quite [number]* doesn't seem to be one. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=were+quite+twenty%3Aeng_us_2012%2C+were+quite+twenty%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwere%20quite%20twenty%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwere%20quite%20twenty%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0). There's a big difference in its frequency between the  1930s and the 1990s, though, so although it may sound wrong to us now, it didn't use to.

Comment: @PeterShor One reason why I ask because the second definition I saw was "really, or actually,"  So I would say "There were actually 50 people at the party," but a British speaker might use quite to mean "in particular" and "actually."

Comment: I would have said that *quite* in these number expressions means *definitely* or *positively*: there is no question that there were fifty people (and maybe a few more).

Comment: The difference is in meaning. If I say something is "quite interesting" I probably mean that it's boring as hell, but because I am super polite (i.e. an Englishman/woman) I cannot bear to make such a direct and insensitive comment. This type of behaviour was very common until the late 1980s, nowadays British people tend to be far more direct and opinionated. Can't post this as an answer b/c this is only my opinion, and how could I prove this?

Comment: @Mari-LouA I asked a British colleague some questions about "quite" and mostly we agreed but in looking at the responses to the question posted, it seems there is a significant difference.  Too bad no one wants to answer this question.  Maybe if I put the word "adjunct" or "relative clause" in the title, it would be taken more seriously...

Comment: I strongly doubt any BrEng speaker would say the phrase "There were quite 50 people at the party" I can't even make out what you are saying there. It should be "almost".  I'd change that sample phrase, if I were you.

Comment: You don't have to name him, and you're genuinely curious, you're not thumping on a drum singling him out for attention. You want to understand, which is *quite* a perfectly legitimate thing. Did you leave a comment under his answer, asking him if the phrase is peculiar to his dialect? He is from the north of England.

Comment: @Mari-LouA ok, edited.

Comment: It's hard to do a comparison between two varieties of a language because to be truthful you'd need unbiased experience in both, and that's difficult to pull off. But quantitatively, a rough, unnuanced search of American and British corpora gives: [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) reports 78952/~450M =~ 18/100K instances of 'quite' and [BNC](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/) reports 39866/~100M =~ 40 per 100K, or __roughly 1/2 as frequent in AmE as BrE__ .

Comment: @Mitch so in BrE, "quite" is used more and probably in ways that AmE speakers wouldn't use...correct?  Technically, the sentences aren't grammatically incorrect.

Comment: @michael_timofeev Both those sentences sound wrong to me (AmE). And 'quite' sounds Britishy to me, like 'indeed', 'shall', or 'cheerio': I'd recognize them, but I'm not sure all the ways it might be used.

Comment: In British English (at least in the books I read) "quite" is often used as a one word response, signifying agreement, often with a disparaging comment.  First lady about third lady: "Humph.  Mutton dressed as lamb."  Second lady: "Quite."

Comment: @michael_timofeev  I believe that Farid's comment on this EL&U question, http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/284088, is also the answer to your question.  I have suggested to Farid that he repost his original comment as a question here, I hope he takes up that suggestion as I believe that his contribution deserves recognition.

Comment: @ab2: Quite. But as Mari-Lou says, Brits alive today would be very unlikely to say anything like *There were quite 50 people at the house.* That would be more typical of upper middle class Victorian speakers. But we do still use ***He had quite a few, He knows quite a lot, He was quite annoyed,...***

Comment: 'Quite a few hundred' fuses 'quite' (probably in the intensifier sense, as in 'rather a lot'), quantifier 'a few' and numeral 'hundred'. I'd have said it wasn't idiomatic, but there are several million (raw data) hits on Google.

Answer (score 4):

Mari-Lou A asked Dan if he could provide dated evidence of a usage of *'quite'* in the form: _'..quite 50 people.'   Here are a couple.

From 'The Missionary Herald at Home and Abroad Vol 51 from 1855:

[image]

http://preview.tinyurl.com/ojz24nf

And James Fennimore Cooper's 'Wynadotte' from 1800:

[image]

http://preview.tinyurl.com/or7wonw

My own little theory is that *'quite'* is derived from *'quit'* (which the OED happily asserts without further comment), and that *'quit'* in its original Latin sense was a balancing or restoring of order to accounts or arrangements, either by keeping them in balance, or in closing them.  Hence in former times to say *'quit'* was to refer to some ledger or accounting system.  *'Not quit fifty'* simply means it hasn't added up to fifty, while *'quit fifty'* meant that it had added up to fifty.  Since the latter assertion usually  didn't need confirmation or reinforcement the use of *'quit'* or *'quite'* wasn't called for, but if one was addressing a doubting audience one would say, *'Yes, quit fifty acres!'*, meaning 'Yes, and I've checked!'.

Comment: Quite bravo of you, if I may say.

Comment: It seems these are on the archaic side...does anyone still say this?

Comment: Here, 'quite' means 'fully'; 'quite 50' probably equates to 50-55.

Answer (score 1):

I (UK) use *quite a* to qualify magnitude in two simple but contradictory ways (so British!) depending on emphasis -

**There were quite a *few* people there** (i.e. there were more people than expected).

**There were *quite* a few people there** (i.e. you are (tactfully) suggesting that the turnout was disappointing).

I also use *quite* to underline the intensity of extreme adjectives -

**He was quite the best pianist I have heard;**

**the jugglers were quite fantastic;**

**quite extraordinary, the way he behaved ...**

The second example in the OP  *...quite 50 people ...* is close to my second usage, although this way of using quite (with numbers) sounds dated to my ears.  Nevertheless the meaning is clear - there were easily 50 people and possibly quite a *few* more.

Comment: Would you say: "I heard quite fifteen people expressing this opinion" rather than "I heard quite a number of people...."?

Comment: I would probably say *I heard at least fifteen people...* . Using *quite* in this way (with numbers) is easy to comprehend but it is an echo in my memory and definitely dated.  Notice as well that it does not mean simply 'quite a number' but more than anticipated/expected.

Comment: If you could find any evidence to support this particular *dated* usage, it's an upvote from me!

Comment: I've just tried Fowler online - but I'm not a subscribing member and there are no freebies.  I'll keep my eyes and ears open !

Comment: As an American, the only example of yours that seems unusual to my ear is "He was quite the best pianist I have heard."

Comment: @David As another American, "quite the best pianist" sounds perfectly OK to me, but that may be because I read a lot of British mysteries.

Comment: @ab2 re-reading it, I would have accepted either, "He was quite a good pianist," or "He was quite the pianist." It is specifically the phrase "quite the best" that throws me, because it implies (to me) that the person is an outstanding example among multiple "best pianists", and you can't ever *have* multiple "best pianists". By definition, there can only ever be a single "best".

Comment: @David I'm confused!  *"He was quite a good pianist"* is a mild compliment;  though 'good' he is unexceptional.  It is not the same at all, to my ears, as saying *"he was quite the pianist"*, which suggests that he exemplifies everything I expect a pianist to be (e.g a showman with moody gaze and eloquent arm gestures).  It is somewhat ambiguous since 'my' notion of a pianist may not necessarily conform to anyone else's!  Less ambiguous, and more complimentary to his pianistic skills (as distinct from his piano-player persona) would be *"he was quite the best pianist I have heard"*.

Comment: @Dan Regardless of "quite a" vs "quite the" (which I think is really where your distinction lies), "quite the *best*" still implies to me that you can have multiple "best pianists". Which you can't.

Comment: @david So interesting!  I agree that you cannot have mutiple "best pianists".  However, to my ears, the 'quite' in "*he was quite the best pianist...*" means 'absolutely' or 'beyond a doubt' (i.e. there is no better pianist than him).  What word (or rephrasing) could you substitute for 'quite' to explain how you hear the usage?

Comment: @David  Agree that there is or should be only one best.  However, the statement "She was among the best whatevers in recent memory" also makes sense.  So there is a category of "the best" which may have more than one person or thing in it.   Small digression:  what really gets me is the phrase "one of the only..."  Grrr!

Answer (score 1):

As an American, I have never heard a construction like, "There were quite 50 people." However, we *would* use its negation, to say something like, "There were not quite 50 people," if there were around, say, 45-49 people. That said, it would probably still be more common to say, "There were almost 50 people." However the latter carries a connotation that the number of people may be more than were expected. The "not quite" phrasing does not carry a similar connotation.

For an AmE parallel to your positive usage, we would instead say something like, "There were barely 50 people," or "There were just barely 50 people." Assuming that the speaker is not misestimating, I would expect this to be around 50-55, and it is emphasizing how many fewer people were there than were expected (say 100+).

EDIT: I agree with a commenter who gave another positive parallel of, "There were actually 50 people." That usage could be used to emphasize either more OR fewer than expected, depending on the context.